# Scaling a site title uniformly with CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress, scale

I have a site title in a Wordpress site that is scaled on hover with some CSS code. The problem is that the title is not scaled uniformly, but runs left. How to solve this?

The HTML code:

```
<div class="site-branding" style="margin-bottom: 58px;">
    <div class="wrap">
        <div class="site-branding-text">
            <h1 class="site-title"><a href="http://dev.infopsi.md/" rel="home">InfoPsi.md</a></h1>
            <p class="site-description">Portalul comunității psihologice din Republica Moldova</p>
        </div><!-- .site-branding-text -->
    </div><!-- .wrap -->
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.site-title {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-transform: initial;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-family: cursive;
    font-weight: initial;
    line-height: initial;
    letter-spacing: initial;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 #CCC, 2px 2px 0 #CCC, 3px 3px 0 #444, 4px 4px 0 #444, 5px 5px 0 #444, 6px 6px 0 #444;
}
.site-title:hover {
    /* CSS3 Transform Effect */
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);     /* Safari & Chrome */
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);        /* Firefox */
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);          /* Opera */
}
.site-title a {
    color: red;
}
```

See a working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/iuriemalai/o4r8xegu/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
display:inline-block
```

to your .site-title CSS rules

Comment: Yeah! So simple! Thank you!

Comment: @lurie transform-origin (defaultvalue is center center ) could also be fine when it's about transform https://jsfiddle.net/o4r8xegu/7/ else , for display i would use display:table to keep the block behavior https://jsfiddle.net/o4r8xegu/8/  ... ;)